# Unix Script to add header in awk script resulting in header on every other line

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to add a header to a split file but with this code the header is appearing every other line:

```
awk -F, '{print "eid,devicetype,meterid,lat,lng" > $7"-"$6".csv"}{print $1",", $2",", $3",", $4",", $5"," >> $7"-"$6".csv"}' path/filename
```

The awk code by itself works but I need to apply a header in the file. The script splits the file based on the values in columns 6 & 7 as well as names the end file with those values. Then it removes columns 6 & 7 it only puts columns 1 - 5 in the output file. This is on Unix in a shell script run from PowerCenter. 
I am sure it is probably simple fix for others more experienced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
awk -F, '!a[$7,$6]++{print "eid,devicetype,meterid,lat,lng" > $7 "-" $6 ".csv"}
  {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 > $7 "-" $6 ".csv"}' OFS=, /path/filename.csv
```

`NR==1` will make sure that header is printed for 1st record.

Comment: It worked for one file but sometimes the export is multiple files. I need it to add a header to all output files. Can you help? Also I have a space aftereach comma in my output files. What do I need to remove those spaces?

Comment: To use comma instead of space in output use `awk -v OFS=, ....` Also if you provide your sample input file in your question I can take a look on why its not working.

Comment: `!a[$7,$6]++` instead of `NR==1` as the pattern might do what he wants. One header for each unique `$7`/`$6` combination.

Comment: Right and you need to parenthesize the string concatenation on the right of the `>` and it should be `>` instead of `>>` on the 2nd line (though functionally it won't matter in this case).

Comment: The !a[$7,$6]++ worked for adding the Header to each file. Thank you. The -v OFS=, is not working for the comma. The spaces are how I am putting the columns into the new files: $1",",$2",",$3",",$4",",$5"," but the results are showing as: column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, where as I would want them to show as column1,column2,column3,column4,column5

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to remove the commas outside of the ". So the final code looks like: awk -F, '!a[$7,$6]++'{print "eid,devicetype,meterid,lat,lng" > $7"-"$6".csv"}{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5 > > $7"-"$6".csv"}' /path/filename.csv

Comment: Great to know it worked out. I updated the answer as per your comment. You may mark any of the answers that worked for you as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ fname = $7 "-" $6 ".csv" }
!seen[fname]++ { print "eid", "devicetype", "meterid", "lat, "lng" > fname}
{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 > fname }
' path/filename
```

Comment: So the `>` only erases the file once, not every time?

Comment: Right, the semantics of `>` and `>>` in awk are different from shell.